# Sorting the dictionary by values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, lambda, dictionary-comprehension

```
sort_orders = sorted(orders.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Can someone explain how `key=lambda x: x[1]` works to sort the dictionary by values?

Comment: Which part of that specifically do you not understand? Do you know what `orders.items()` is? How the `key` argument is used? What a `lambda` does? Indexing? Recomended reading: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.items()` returns itemview object.
It is something like:

```
dict_items([('key_1', 'val_1'), ('key_2', 'val_2'), ('key_3', 'val_3')])
```

so if you pass this object to sorted and put in the key argument as `lambda x: x[1]` it will sort the itemview object basis the first index of every tuple inside the itemview. It will further set that order as descending as the reverse argument is set to True

If I try to explain this via an example consider this:

```
orders={'order_1':'Pizza','order_2':'Chicken','order_3':'Lasagne'}

sort_orders = sorted(orders.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

print(sort_orders) #1

print(orders.items()) #2
```

The #1 Print gives you:

```
[('order_1', 'Pizza'), ('order_3', 'Lasagne'), ('order_2', 'Chicken')]
```

The #2 Print gives you:

```
dict_items([('order_2', 'Chicken'), ('order_1', 'Pizza'), ('order_3', 'Lasagne')])
```

Visit [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) python documentation on sorting for more information related to sorted

Hope this helps !